# How to gracefully handle DoesNotExist exception when admin user is not found?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a created_by field in my model which defaults to the admin user upon object creation. I am fetching the admin user using this piece of code,

```
admin_user_name = settings.ADMIN_USER_NAME
admin = User.objects.get(username=admin_user_name)
```

Now if I have to handle the object.DoesNotExist exception like

```
try:
   admin_user_name = settings.ADMIN_USER_NAME
   admin = User.objects.get(username=admin_user_name)
except User.DoesNotExist:
    # handle the exception gracefully
```

How do I handle the exception without throwing an error in such a case?

Update:
The created_by field is made available by inheriting the following

```
class AbstractUserBase(models.Model):
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User,related_name='%(class)s_createdby',on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

Comment: It seems odd to me to have an `ADMIN_USER_NAME` (there is only one admin? and you identify that by the username?). Why not set it to `None`/`NULL` by default?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem yes, i have only one admin. The field is defined by ```created_by = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='%(class)s_createdby', on_delete=models.CASCADE)``` , which cannot be None/NULL and hence, cannot return None

Comment: but why not make it nullable? Furthermore usually one uses `settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL` to refer to the user model to make it more convenient to swap in a custom user model: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I've updated the question, is there any other way without making it nullable?